# How can I have "Current Users" portlet back?

Tags: liferay, portlet

I have closed "Current Users" portlet from the demo installation and now can't open it back -- there is no such a portlet in a list.

How one can have it back on page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Current Users" portlet is in fact just a "Web Content Display" portlet that's been renamed. So if you add a "Web Content Display" portlet on to your page and set then find the piece of Web Content called: "Welcome Login" (it's ID on mine was 10232, but this may be different for you) and set that as the content to be displayed you'll get it back. Or you can add a new piece of web content with the code below:

```
    <p><style type="text/css"> .loginuser { margin-top:5px; width:100%; display:block; text-decoration:none; padding: 2px; padding-bottom: 10px; } .loginuser h2 { margin:0; font-size:14px; /*text-align:center;*/ } .loginuser a { display:block; padding-left: 20px; margin-left: 95px; margin-top: 2px; } .loginuser img { padding:2px; margin-right: 5px; } .loginuser:hover { background-color: #CED9E2; /*cursor:pointer;*/ } .express_login { background: url("/html/icons/login.png") no-repeat; } .public_pages { background: url("/html/themes/classic/images/common/view_tasks.png") no-repeat; } </style></p>
<form name="loginadmin" method="post" action="/web/guest/home">
    <input type="hidden" value="58" name="p_p_id" /> <input type="hidden" value="1" name="p_p_lifecycle" /> <input type="hidden" value="view" name="p_p_mode" /> <input type="hidden" value="maximized" name="p_p_state" /> <input type="hidden" value="/login/login" name="_58_struts_action" /> <input type="hidden" value="bruno@7cogs.com" name="_58_login" /> <input type="hidden" value="bruno" name="_58_password" />
    <div title="Login: bruno@7cogs.com, Password: bruno" class="loginuser">
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 4px;" class="user-profile-image"><img width="80" class="avatar" alt="" src="/image/user_portrait?screenName=bruno&amp;companyId=10112&amp;t=1228845375900" /></div>
    <h2>Bruno (Admin)</h2>
    <div>The admin has full control over the entire portal, allowing modification and creation of users, communitities, and roles. <a class="public_pages" href="/web/bruno">View bruno's public page</a> <a onclick="document.loginadmin.submit();return false;" class="express_login" href="#">Login as bruno</a></div>
    </div>
</form>
<form name="loginrich" method="post" action="/web/guest/home">
    <input type="hidden" value="58" name="p_p_id" /> <input type="hidden" value="1" name="p_p_lifecycle" /> <input type="hidden" value="view" name="p_p_mode" /> <input type="hidden" value="maximized" name="p_p_state" /> <input type="hidden" value="/login/login" name="_58_struts_action" /> <input type="hidden" value="richard@7cogs.com" name="_58_login" /> <input type="hidden" value="richard" name="_58_password" />
    <div title="Login: richard@7cogs.com, Password: richard" class="loginuser">
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 4px;" class="user-profile-image"><img width="80" class="avatar" alt="" src="/image/user_portrait?screenName=richard&amp;companyId=10112&amp;t=1228845375871" /></div>
    <h2>Richard Publisher</h2>
    <div>Richard has article submission rights for the content management system. <a class="public_pages" href="/web/richard">View richard's public page</a> <a onclick="document.loginrich.submit();return false;" class="express_login" href="#">Login as richard</a></div>
    </div>
</form>
<form name="loginmichelle" method="post" action="/web/guest/home">
    <input type="hidden" value="58" name="p_p_id" /> <input type="hidden" value="1" name="p_p_lifecycle" /> <input type="hidden" value="view" name="p_p_mode" /> <input type="hidden" value="maximized" name="p_p_state" /> <input type="hidden" value="/login/login" name="_58_struts_action" /> <input type="hidden" value="michelle@7cogs.com" name="_58_login" /> <input type="hidden" value="michelle" name="_58_password" />
    <div title="Login: michelle@7cogs.com, Password: michelle" class="loginuser">
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 4px;" class="user-profile-image"><img width="80" class="avatar" alt="" src="/image/user_portrait?screenName=michelle&amp;companyId=10112&amp;t=1228845375823" /></div>
    <h2>Michelle Editor</h2>
    <div>Michelle has control over the staging and layout of all articles as well as publishing rights for workflow and the content management system. <a class="public_pages" href="/web/michelle">View michelle's public page</a> <a onclick="document.loginmichelle.submit();return false;" class="express_login" href="#">Login as michelle</a></div>
    </div>
</form>
<form name="loginjohn" method="post" action="/web/guest/home">
    <input type="hidden" value="58" name="p_p_id" /> <input type="hidden" value="1" name="p_p_lifecycle" /> <input type="hidden" value="view" name="p_p_mode" /> <input type="hidden" value="maximized" name="p_p_state" /> <input type="hidden" value="/login/login" name="_58_struts_action" /> <input type="hidden" value="john@7cogs.com" name="_58_login" /> <input type="hidden" value="john" name="_58_password" />
    <div title="Login: john@7cogs.com, Password: john" class="loginuser">
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 4px;" class="user-profile-image"><img width="80" class="avatar" alt="" src="/image/user_portrait?screenName=john&amp;companyId=10112&amp;t=1228845375887" /></div>
    <h2>John Regular User</h2>
    <div>John is a user with minimum rights within the portal.
    <div><a class="public_pages" href="/web/john">View john's public page</a> <a onclick="document.loginjohn.submit();return false;" class="express_login" href="#">Login as john</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Hope this helps!